# Error: User.Name does not exists on Validation Rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule, user, name

I have an error creating Validation Rule and is strange. Here is the VR:

```
AND(!$Setup.Bypass__c.ValidationRule__c,
!$Permission.IntegrationPermissions,
$User.Name != $Label.USER_MANAGER,
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active")))
```

And... when I check the syntax, I have this response:

***Error: Field Name does not exist. Check spelling.***

But User has Name field, obviously. So I think I cannot access this field on VR.

Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: Does the error goes away if you remove `$User.Name != $Label.USER_MANAGER,` from formula? Otherwise try removing each condition one by one until you know the exact cause.

Comment: In fact, if I put `$User.Username != $Label.USER_MANAGER,` it works. But in this case, I would like to control the flow through Name instead Username.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the concatenation of FirstName and LastName fields, no idea why Name is not available

```
($User.FirstName & ' ' &  $User.LastName) != $Label.USER_MANAGER
```

But I would recommend you to use a Field to hold if a user is a manager

Comment: Okay, is not exactly that I wanted to, but is a nice alternative. Thank you!